# When upgrading the Google internal test version, the code correction is not reflected well

Tags: android, react-native, flutter, kotlin, google-play

I am using windows os and react-native and android. I released my project to the Google Play Store internal test.

I'm trying to fix my code.

After that, even if you download the app, the modified code is not reflected. I have to repeat the previous method twice(which is (gradlew clean,gradlew app:assembleRelease, Upload version upgrade to Google Play )) for the code modification to be reflected.

Why does this process have to be repeated twice for code reflection to occur? Code reflection has to be done only once.

Comment: Are you tracking the version changes on Google play? After you upload a new version, does the store reflect the newer version or it still displays the old one?

Comment: @Konstantin
The version is displayed as the latest version as a number (ex. 1-> 2) However, when I make some code changes to the front in version 2, the code changes are not reflected. The code is still reflected as version 1 of the code.